# Changing Android ActionBar Tab Text style not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I've tried everything I've found to change Actionbar Tab's text color. I've come up with this:

```
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

            <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
                <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
                <!-- Support library compatibility -->
                <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
            </style>

            <!-- ActionBar styles -->
            <style name="ActionBar"
                parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
                <!-- Support library compatibility -->
                <item name="background">@color/actionbar_background</item>
                <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitleText</item>
                <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTabText</item>
                <item name="displayOptions">showHome|showTitle</item>
                <item name="logo">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
            </style>

            <!-- ActionBar title text -->
            <style name="ActionBarTitleText"
                parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
                <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
                <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_large</item>
            </style>

            <!-- ActionBar TABs -->
            <style name="ActionBarTabText"
                parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
                <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_tab_text</item>
                <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_medium</item>
                <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
            </style>
</resources>
```

Still actionbar tabs show white textcolor and uppercase texts.

Any idea what could be possibly going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`, then remove below two lines from your layout file,

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "android:" versions of these two lines.

@style/ActionBarTabText
showHome|showTitle